# Form field value doesnt get sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, request

So I have a RoR form using simple_form gem, and the strange thing is, if I put a string in a field which has integer type in the table, it doesnt even get sent, it just sends an empty string even if I put something like 'sdfsd' there, why does it happen?

Form:

```
= simple_form_for :product do |p|
 = p.input :price
 = p.button :submit
```

DB Table:

```
 create_table :products do |t|      
  t.integer :price, null: false
 end
```

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :price, presence: true, inclusion: {in: 1..100}

end
```

and so if type 'blah blah' into the price field, it'll send:

Parameters: {"product"} => {"price" => ""}

Comment: some code snippet would help us to help you better :)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Seems odd that character values don't even get sent, depriving us of an opportunity to validate and provide an error message. Did you find a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide code, but to give you something to digest, the [`simple_form` documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage) shows you can just use `f.input :attribute_name`, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should take your attribute field type, and create a field around it.

--

When you mention you've got an `integer` field, and it "doesn't get sent", there are 3 potential issues you should ensure you haven't fallen foul of:

1. Is the `attribute` in your db? (may have forgotten to run `rake db:migrate`, although unlikely
2. Are you calling the attribute in your `form` correctly?
3. Are you permitting the data to pass to your model using the [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) method?

I would surmise your problem is with #3 - to fix, you should do this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @model = Model.new(model_params)
      @model.save
   end

   private

   def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:attributes)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added a little code snippet to the question to explain what I meant, and it works fine if I type a number in the field, it gets validated, it gets saved if its correct and etc, but if I try to send a string instead of a number, it doesnt even go to the server for validation, just an empty string... I dont have any problems with it, just wonder why it happens this way....

Comment: It's probably because you've got it set as an `integer` in the database. How can you expect an `integer` to handle a `string`? If you used `form_for` (in place of `simple_form`, you'll probably see an error saying you can't save a `string` to an `integer` field type

Comment: I understand all that, I just thought it would at least send it to the server and then just show a validation error

Comment: :) The best way to find out will be to test with `form_for`. I think it's a `simple_form` issue :)